# Unable to change node version using nvm

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I am unable to resolve this error. I don't even know what's causing it. I have the latest version of npm and the most stable version of node.

```
$ nvm use 0.10.40
```

/Users/Test/.nvm/v0.10.40/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:27

```
console.error(`a bug known to break npm. Please update to at least ${r
                  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at /Users/Test/.nvm/v0.10.40/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:19:21
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Test/.nvm/v0.10.40/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:92:3)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to ""
Run `npm config delete prefix` or `nvm use --delete-prefix v0.10.40` to unset it.

I tried to run nvm use --delete-prefix v0.10.40 but that gives me the same error as well.

Comment: Try installing npm again with nvm. i solved this issue by following this guide
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need up update `Node.js` which you can do by visiting

- https://nodejs.org/en/

See:

- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18963

Answer (score 0):

Update your nodejs version, install the nvm https://github.com/creationix/nvm.
Later install the version choice of nodejs

```
# e.g, replace for a current version
nvm install 9.3.0
```